# How to read SPD DeviceID (PnP) in UWP app for unpaired device?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth

I am using following code to identify my device:

```
string[] properties = new string[] {
        "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress",
        "System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.VendorId",
        "System.DeviceInterface.Bluetooth.ProductId"
    };

var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false);
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector, properties);

if (devices[0].Properties.TryGetValue(properties[1], out object vendorIdValue))
{
    vendorId = (ushort?)vendorIdValue ?? (ushort)0;
}
if (devices[0].Properties.TryGetValue(properties[2], out object productIdValue))
{
    productId = (ushort?)productIdValue ?? (ushort)0;
}
```

However when device is unpaired, vendorId and productId are always null (0). When device is paired I am able to read VId and PId. How I can get these properties for unpaired device?

Comment: Try true instead of false : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.getdeviceselectorfrompairingstate?view=winrt-19041

Comment: @jdweng but I want it to be false, since I want to enumerate unpaired devices.

Comment: In you properties do you need address when searching? The properties is a search filter and you want to find the address, not use the address in the search.

Comment: I do not need address. It what sense it is search filter? Because nothing is filtered based on this address, I am just using this property to later create `BluetoothDevice` (if pid and vid match).

Answer (score 0):

When the device is not paired, some information (endpoint) will be disclosed, like Id or device name, but this part of the information does not contain the vid and pid you need. These information will be disclosed after pairing.

You can do a test, pair a certain device, and then unpair, you can find that as long as the device has been paired, even if the pairing is canceled, you can still get the vid and pid. But after restarting the device, the vid and pid of the device will no longer be obtained.

Comment: But this makes no sense, as SDP is designed to check if this is device I am looking for. In my app I want to prompt user to pair with my device, not prompt him to pair with all nearby devices to check whether they are my device. This design is nonsensical, also other platforms do not have such restrictions. Even UWP itself discloses PID and VID for unpaired BLE devices, just not for BT Classic.